# automatically copy contents of inserted media to folder

Tags: macos, file, shell, copy, applescript

I have a lot of previously backed up data burned on CDs/DVDs to copy back to my hard drive.
I'm looking for a way to dump everything on an inserted media to some folder (pref. created by volume name), by some automated way (pref. via *applescript* or *shell script*) that would:

- create folder by volume name dump
- dump contents of inserted media in folder
- eject media
- wait for next media to be inserted

My problem resides in the fact the all of these disks have random volume labels (it's not exactly random, but let's go with random to be sure).

Since I don't know the volume label beforehand, and every mount point (in /Volumes) and device name (in /dev) is dynamically assigned on Mac, where do I start to find what media has just been inserted (assuming to no other devices or media are going to be inserted for the time of the script).

I've been looking for quite some time, but most things I found deal with known volume labels.

Any ideas would be very appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of drutil and diskutil. drutil can give you the device path and using that diskutil can give you the volume name. The tough part is parsing the results to get what you want.

Try this...

```
set diskName to cdDVDName()
if diskName is missing value then error "Could not get the name of the inserted disk"
diskName

on cdDVDName()
    set diskName to missing value
    try
        set theConst to "Volume Name: "
        set drutilStatus to do shell script "drutil status -drive internal | grep \"/dev/\""
        set theDrive to "/dev/" & item -1 of (words of drutilStatus)
        set diskutilInfo to do shell script "diskutil info " & theDrive & " | grep \"" & theConst & "\""

        set text item delimiters to theConst
        set a to text items of diskutilInfo
        set text item delimiters to ""
        set diskName to item -1 of a
        repeat while diskName begins with space
            set diskName to text 2 thru -1 of diskName
        end repeat
        repeat while diskName ends with space
            set diskName to text 1 thru -2 of diskName
        end repeat
    end try
    return diskName
end cdDVDName
```

This script will eject the cd/dvd...

```
do shell script "drutil tray eject"
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot :) Learned a couple of things with this script. Should be attachable to a folder action of /Volumes. The only thing left to figure is, this script showed me a couple of discs i have don't seem to have a volume label, although the Finder shows me smth like '0209011415', but diskutil shows me the disk effectively has no label.